# "Support" of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

1. I was wondering if there is some
   definition for "support" of a
   measure in the sense that one or
   both of the following can be true:

   - one measure is absolutely continuous    with respect to
     another measure, if and only if    the support
     of the former is inside    the
     support of the latter?
   - two measures are mutually singular    (as in Rudin's Real and
     Complex    Analysis), if and only if the
     supports of the two    measures are
     disjoint?
2. The definition for [support
   of a measure in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28measure_theory%29) relies
   on that the measurable space is also a
   topological space. I would like to
   know if it makes sense to define
   support of a measure solely on a
   measurable space?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. No way: Think of Lebesgue measure and a point measure.
2. You can often speak of the support up to a null-set, but in order to single out a specific support you need further structure on your measure space.

**Added:** In 2. I was deliberately a bit sloppy. A sufficient condition for the existence of a good notion of support is a class of null sets closed under *arbitrary* unions. The union of those null-sets is then the largest such $\mu$-null set and its complement deserves the name of support of $\mu$. For instance, if $\mu$ happens to be a Radon measure on a locally compact space, you can take the class of *open* $\mu$-null sets and the union of those is precisely the complement of the (closed) support of $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks! For 1, do you mean: neither of Lebesgue measure and a Dirac measure is absolutely continuous wrt the other, nor are they mutually singular; this fact cannot be related to "support" of a measure, no matter how we define it?

Comment: @Tim: The Lebesgue measure and a point measure are clearly mutually singular. The support of a measure *should be* the smallest set outside of which a measure always vanishes. Now a point measure is obviously supported at that point, while Lebesgue measure has full support and you could always pick a point measure inside the "support" of the Lebesgue measure.